# Cursor visibility in Text SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have  a non editable text in SWT.

```
final Text textArea = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
textArea.setVisible(false);
textArea.setEditable(false);
Color color=new Color(display,255,255,255);
textArea.setBackground(color);
```

When I click on the text area, the cursor is still visible. I do not want the cursor to be visible at all. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the text cursor/caret?

Comment: Yes.I meant the text cursor.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the hide "blinking text cursor in the text", disable the `Text` by calling `Text#setEnabled(false)`.

If you don't want the mouse cursor to change to the text cursor when you hover over the text, set the `Cursor` of the `Text` to `SWT.CURSOR_ARROW` by calling `Text#setCursor(int)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    text.setText("fdfsdfsd");
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setEnabled(false);
    text.setCursor(Display.getCurrent().getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_ARROW));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully.Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Label instead of Text.